# ImportError while import a Python file in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working in a Python 3 project using Pycharm and I have a problem importing a file. This is my project structure:

```
twixer
  |----- docs
  |----- twixer
           |----- __init__.py
           |----- config.ini
           |----- facepp.py
           |----- twixer.py
  |----- setup.py
```

In twixer.py I have the next line:

```
import twixer.facepp
```

But that line throws this error when I run the project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/David/PycharmProjects/twixer-py/twixer/twixer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import twixer.facepp
  File "D:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\twixer-py\twixer\twixer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import twixer.facepp
ImportError: No module named 'twixer.facepp'; 'twixer' is not a package
```

I have no idea about how to solve this problem. I tried to change the way I import the file without luck. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: wouldnt `import faceapp` do the job ?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but Pycharm shows this error: No module named facepp.

Comment: @ThePavolC not sure about what happens but I renamed root folder to 'twixer-py' and back to 'twixer' and now import facepp works, but Pycharm still shows the same error on the editor.

Comment: How do you run the project? Did you used your setup.py to install it?

Comment: @pacholik Right click over twixer.py and Run. Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

I made the same beginner mistake of *executing the code in the console* instead of **running it** (right click in file and select "`Run '_your_python_file_'`").

Hope this can help others beginners.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long if answer it in coments, so post it here, I dont know if it works for you or not, just provide some idea.
I had similar issue, and I solved it by adding the module in python path

```
hello-world
      |----- helpers
               |----- __init__.py
               |----- helper.py
               |----- sdp_helper.py
      |----- say-hello
               |----- __init__.py
               |----- say_hello.py
```

When I  on use the scripts on console:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/haifzhan/hello-world/helpers")
import helper
import sdp_helper
```

When I use the module in Pycharm, the above imports are not working, so I use:

```
from hello-world.helpers import helper
from hello-world.helpers import sdp_helper
```

Comment: But in question, `faceapp.py` and `twixer.py` are in the same folder. You should be able to import .py files from same folder

Answer (score 0):

base on the traceback of your error, I think your problem may be that your module and package have the same name, thus when you try to import  twixer.facepp, Python uses its [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) "In the face of ambiguity refuse the temptation to guess".

Python avoids guessing if you meant import the module twixer or import the package twixer, thus its raise an error for you to correct it.

You could also solve this without changing your module/package name (although I would recommend that), by using a [relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), i.e

```
from . import facepp
```

I hope it helps ;)